# Checkbox does not hide a div

Tags: html, css

Hello i want to make a div which hides when i check the checkbox in pure HTML and CSS.

```css
.sort__checkbox:checked ~ .sort {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label><input class="sort__checkbox" type="checkbox"> Sort </label>
<div class="sort">
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  <form class = "sort__form" method="GET" action="{% url 'sort-page' %}">
    <input type="range" name="sort" class="sort__input">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `~` is for siblings, and your input has none

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `<label>` around sort alone, and that should work.

Or move it inside.

```html
<input class="sort__checkbox" type="checkbox"><label> Sort</label>
  <div class="sort">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
    <form class="sort__form" method="GET" action="{% url 'sort-page' %}">
      <input type="range" name="sort" class="sort__input">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Divs can't be children of labels. That's invalid HTML. And how is that a typo?

Comment: MaciejWojtkowiak You're welcome, but please don't assume people around you are all men in the future.

@j08691 I have edited my answer, you are right. I also used typo as a buzzword for mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Do not place your checkbox inside your label tag. It's not recommended because they are two different elements. Assign an ID to your checkbox and use it for your label.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Then, make sure your target div is hidden by default. Like this. `.sort { display: none; }`

Lastly, use `input[type="checkbox"]:checked.sort__checkbox { display: block; }` to show the div when your checkbox is checked.

Here's a full example. Tested and works.

```css
.sort {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked.sort__checkbox~.sort {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input class="sort__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox">
<label for="my-checkbox">Sort</label>
<div class="sort">
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  <form class="sort__form" method="GET" action="{% url 'sort-page' %}">
    <input type="range" name="sort" class="sort__input">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: _"Do not place your checkbox inside your label tag. It's not recommended because they are two different elements"_ This is wrong. There's absolutely nothing wrong with placing a checkbox in a label

Comment: I never said is wrong, in fact both are correct but personally I don't recommend it because based in my experience is much less flexible when styling with CSS. This is my humble option.